# Ansible Vault: Including the password of file within the playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I need to run a Playbook with Inventory file, which is password protected. I know that we can give password by *prompt (when running the playbook)* or using *secret file which have the password of inventory*.

My question is "**is there a way to specify inventory file's password within the playbook**"

Answer (score 0):

The vault password can be exported to the machine where you want to run the ansible playbook (like a local machine or Jenkins, etc.) and run the playbook as follows:

#### To export the ansible vault password

```
export VAULT_PASSWORD=valut-password-here
```

Then you can use it in two ways, either directly.

```
ansible-playbook your-playbook.yml --vault-password-file <(cat <<<"$VAULT_PASSWORD")
```

By using the Python OS module, you can read from the environment and then pass it to the Ansible Playbook.

```
ansible-playbook your-playbook.yml --vault-password-file ./vault_password.py
```

where `vault_password.py` has this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
print os.environ['VAULT_PASSWORD']
```